# Problem In understanding distribuitional section

Tags: vector-bundles, schwartz-distributions

In this   post  [Observables](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-observables/) By Urs Schreiber he denotes   the space of distributional sections in defenition 7.9 by  $ \Gamma_{\Sigma}^{\prime}\left(E^*\right) $

That is if $u \in \Gamma_{\Sigma}^{\prime}\left(E^*\right) $  than $u$ is a linear functional that takes as argument sections of a vector bundle $E$

In the same post he has  proposition 7.10

> Let $E \stackrel{f b}{\rightarrow} \Sigma$ be a smooth vector bundle over Minkowski spacetime and let $s \in\{c p, \pm c p, s c p, t c p\}$ be any of the support conditions from def. $2.36$.
> Then the operation of regarding a compactly supported smooth section of the dual vector bundle as a functional on sections with this support property is a dense subspace inclusion into the topological vector space of distributional sections from def. 7.9:
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \Gamma_{\Sigma, \mathrm{cp}}\left(E^*\right) & \stackrel{u_{(-)}}{\longrightarrow} & \Gamma_{\Sigma, S}^{\prime}(E) \\
> b & \mapsto & \left(\Phi \mapsto \int_{\Sigma} b(x) \cdot \Phi(x) \operatorname{dvol}_{\Sigma}(x)\right)
> \end{array}
> $$

In my understanding $u_{()}$ is a map from the space of sections of the dual bundle to the space of the distributional section .

Why  $ u_{()} \in \Gamma_{\Sigma, s}^{\prime}(E)$ ? Shouldn't we have $ u_{()} \in \Gamma_{\Sigma, s}^{\prime}(E^*)$

Comment: Yes, looks like a typo.